# How to restart an Alfresco subsystem? (Not restart the whole Alfresco)

Tags: alfresco

An [Alfresco manual](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/topic/com.alfresco.enterprise.doc/tasks/OOo-subsystems-config.html) contains this instruction:

> Restart the subsystem.

I didn't even know it was possible to restart just a subsystem without restarting the whole Alfresco.

How to do?

Comment: Are you on the Community or the Enterprise edition of Alfresco?

Comment: @Gagravarr: Enterprise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're on Enterprise, you can [stop and start subsystems through JMX](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Alfresco_Subsystems#JMX_.28Enterprise_only.29)

If you've not worked with JMX before, then the [Alfresco wiki](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/JMX) has quite a bit of information on it, and the [Enterprise Documentation](http://docs.alfresco.com/3.4/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.alfresco.Enterprise_3_4_0.doc%2Ftasks%2Fjmx-access.html) covers it too, including a guide to using JConsole.

(You can also start and stop subsystems via code, if you need to do it programatically, the relevant code is in the *org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems* package)